# this.setState() doesn't render fetched Firebase pictures

Tags: reactjs, firebase, fetch, setstate

I am trying to fetch all pictures from a Firebase storage.

The fetching works fine with the function _loadImages, but the fetched images are not shown.

I have the same issue with React and React Native.

I am trying since days but it just doesn't re-render the images.

Anyone an idea how I can re-render the fetched images?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Firebase from '../functions/Firebase'

class Images extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        Firebase.init();
        this.state = {
            imageUrl: "",
            imageArray: [
                "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1571831284707-b14ca2e0da5f?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60",
                "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1494537176433-7a3c4ef2046f?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60",
                "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1579170130266-b77007d32ab5?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60",
                "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1565047946982-5ca5149ce14c?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60",
            ],
            loading: false,

        }
    }

    _loadImages = () => {
        const imageArray = []
        var storage = Firebase.storage
        var storageRef = storage.ref()
        var listRef = storageRef.child("images/")
        listRef.listAll().then((res) => {
            res.items.map((itemRef) => {
                var urlFB = itemRef.name
                var getPictureURL = 'images/'.concat(urlFB)
                var starsRef = storageRef.child(getPictureURL)
                starsRef.getDownloadURL().then((url) => {
                    imageArray.push(url)
                })
            })
        })
        this.setState({ imageArray })
    }

    _localLoadImages = () => {
        this.setState({ loading: true })
        this._loadImages()
        this.setState({ loading: false })

    }

    handleUpload = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
    }

    render() {
        let imageUrlArray = this.state.imageArray
        const images = imageUrlArray.map((item, i) => {
            return (
                <img
                    className="SingleImage"
                    src={item}
                    key={item}></img>
            )
        })
        return (
            <div className="Images" >
                {images}
                <button type='button' onClick={() => this._localLoadImages()}>Load Images!</button>
            </div >
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are setting it to the state before the asynchronous function is done executing.

```
_loadImages = () => {
        const imageArray = []
        var storage = Firebase.storage
        var storageRef = storage.ref()
        var listRef = storageRef.child("images/")
        listRef.listAll().then((res) => {
            res.items.map((itemRef) => {
                var urlFB = itemRef.name
                var getPictureURL = 'images/'.concat(urlFB)
                var starsRef = storageRef.child(getPictureURL)
                starsRef.getDownloadURL().then((url) => {
                    imageArray.push(url)
                    this.setState({ imageArray })
                })
            })
        })

    }
```

Or with `async/await`,

```
_loadImages = async () => {
        const imageArray = []
        const storage = Firebase.storage
        const storageRef = storage.ref()
        const listRef = storageRef.child("images/")
        const list = await listRef.listAll();
        list.items.map((itemRef) => {
            var urlFB = itemRef.name
            var getPictureURL = 'images/' + urlFB;
            var starsRef = storageRef.child(getPictureURL)
            const url = starsRef.getDownloadURL();
            imageArray.push(url);
        });
        this.setState({ imageArray });
    }
```

Comment: It works like that! Thank you very much. 
But now we overwrite the state multiple times. Wouldn't it be better to overwrite it just once, after fetching the whole array?
Can you tell me why it didn't work even if the state was updated and I forcedUpdate (this.forceUpdate()) with another Button?

Comment: It's due to the synchronous nature of execution. Javascript executes the entire function in one go. The asynchronous function (firebase call) only resolves later in time.

Comment: You should try to avoid using forceUpdate. I assume you are rerendering your component because of this line `let imageUrlArray = this.state.imageArray`. Try doing this in a componentDidMount function.

Comment: Thank you very much, guys! I highly appreciate your answers. :)